# how to calculate multiple user input in python

Tags: python, input, calculation

I'm new to python and I was trying to write a code like this

print("please enter random number")

score1 =input()

score2 =input()

score3 =input()

print("your final number is", score1 + score2 + score3)

it still turns out with no error but I want to calculate score1 and score2 and score3 to get a final result

Comment: You didn't explain your issue, I imagine you have 1+2+3 = 123 instead of 6?

Comment: as you're new, input() captures user-input in string format. But arithmatic operation is available for int and float only. So you're required to typecast it